# Spring RestTemplate POST sends empty request body

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am puzzled why restTemplate.postForEntity(endpoint, request, Response.class) sending empty request body.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    HttpEntity<Request> request = new HttpEntity<Request>(request , headers);

    ResponseEntity<Response> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(endpoint, request, Response.class);
```

Any ideas?

Request is simple POJO annotated by @JsonComponent at class level

RestTemplate logging writes out the 'request' body: o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Writing [Request [name=my test name, type=type1 ...

In an http request interceptor: 
Sending POST request to http://endpoint/api/testEndpoint: [{}]

Comment: Figured this out. It was due to POJO class missing the getters.